# Evaluating infix expression with two stacks in python

Tags: python, expression, infix-notation, evaluate

This is my first time asking a question on here, and I am only doing this because I have spent the past week trying to figure this out and haven't been able to. I found similar questions, but the results did not help me. I have to take an infix expression and calculate the results using two stacks, one for the operator and one for the numbers. An example would be `6 - ( 5 - 3 ) * ( 4 + 2 ) = -6` or `3 * 11 / 8 + 5 – 4 * 7 = -18.875.` I just cannot figure out how to get this to work. Currently my code is this:

```
class NumStack:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty stack."""
        self._data = []                         #nonpublic list instance

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of elements in the stack."""
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if the stack is empty."""
        return len(self._data) == 0

    def push(self,e):
        """Add element e to the top of the stack."""
        self._data.append(e)                    #new item stored at end of list
        print(self._data)

    def top(self):
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty"""

        if self.is_empty():
            return
        return self._data[-1]                   #the last item in the list

    def pop(self):
        """Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e, LIFO)

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty."""

        if self.is_empty():
            return "empty"
        return self._data.pop()                 #remove last item from list

    def str(self):
        return self._data

class OperatorStack:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty stack."""
        self._data = []                         #nonpublic list instance

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of elements in the stack."""
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if the stack is empty."""
        length = len(self._data)
        if length == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def push(self,e):
        """Add element e to the top of the stack."""
        self._data.append(e)                    #new item stored at end of list
        print(self._data)

    def top(self):
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty"""

        if self.is_empty():
            return
        return self._data[-1]                   #the last item in the list

    def pop(self):
        """Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e, LIFO)

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty."""

        length = len(self)
        if length == 0:
            print("list is empty")
        else:

            if self.is_empty():
                return
            return self._data.pop()

    def str(self):
        return self._data



def main():
    expression = str(input("Enter an expression: "))
    expression = expression.split()
    print(expression)
    N = NumStack()
    O = OperatorStack()   
    new = []
    NewOP = []
    NewNum = [0,0]




    for e in expression:
        if e == '(' or e == ')' or e == '+' or e == '-' or e == '*' or e == '/':
            O.push(e)
        else:
            N.push(e)

    while O.is_empty() == False or N.is_empty() == False:


        TmpOp = O.top()
        if TmpOp == ')':
            O.pop()
        elif TmpOp == '(':
            O.pop()
        if TmpOp != '(' and TmpOp != ')':
            new.append(N.pop())
            new.append(O.pop())

        print(TmpOp)

        while TmpOp == ')':

            if N.top() != "empty":
                NewNum[1] = N.pop()
            if N.top() != "empty":
                NewNum[0] = N.top()
                print(NewNum[0],NewNum[1])

            if O.pop() == '+':
                num = float(NewNum[1]) + float(NewNum[0])
                new.append(num)
                print(num)
                O.pop()
                break



            elif O.pop() == '-':
                num = float(NewNum[0]) - float(NewNum[1])
                new.append(num)
                print(num)
                O.pop()
                break



            elif O.pop() == '*':
                num = NewNum[1]*NewNum[0]
                new.append(num)
                print(num)
                # O.pop()
                break



            elif O.pop() == '/':
                num = NewNum[1]/NewNum[0]
                new.append(num)
                print(num)
                #  O.pop()
                break



            if O.top() == ')':
                O.pop()
                break

            if O.__len__() == 0 and N.__len__() == 0:
                break
        continue
        while TmpOp != ')' and TmpOp != '(':
            new.append(N.pop())
            new.append(O.pop())
            print(new)

            if O.__len__() == 0 and N.__len__() == 0:
                break


        print(new)





main()
```

I believe my classes to be correct, I just cannot find a way of extracting the needed information correctly. I am trying to pop the items into a list and when I get to a parenthesis I go ahead and perform the calculation. If I could just get the correct numbers into my list then I know I can get it to work. I just need to get the "new" to contain the correct numbers. With the problem: `"6 - ( 5 - 3 ) * ( 4 + 2 )"` I should get `[6.0, '*', 2.0, '-', 6]`. It is not coming out to that. I really appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant [6.0, '*', 2.0, '-', 6]. I would just take this and reverse it to get it back into the original form except with the things that are in parenthesis already converted. From there it would be simple calculations and telling it which order to go in.

Comment: I feel like stacks aren't good enough -- Especially if you need to deal with parens, operator precedence, etc.  For something like this, It seems like a _tree_ is the best data structure.

Comment: I am required to use stacks for a class I am taking.